# WSO2 EI 6.6.0 Class Mediator not being able to use SOAP call return content

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have the following API in EI 6.6.0:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="sample" context="/sample">
   <resource methods="POST">
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                  <soap:Body>
                     <P xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                        <P1>$1</P1>
                        <P2>$2</P2>
                        <P3>$3</P3>
                     </P>
                  </soap:Body>
               </soap:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.p1" />
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.p2" />
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.p3" />
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full" />
         <property name="Content-Type" value="text/xml;charset=UTF-8" scope="axis2"/>
         <header name="Accept" scope="transport" value="text/xml"/>
        <call>
         <endpoint>
            <wsdl Action="name_of_the_action" service="name_of_the_service" port="name_of_soap_port" uri="http://<ip>/path?WSDL" />
         </endpoint>
        </call> 
      
        <class name="my_mediator_package"></class>
        <log level="full" />
        <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
           <format>
              <retorno xmlns="">
                 <msg>$1</msg>
              </retorno>
           </format>
           <args>
              <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('property_set_on_mediator')" />
           </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
        <respond />
    </inSequence>
      
    <outSequence>
      </outSequence>

      <faultSequence>
         <property name="text" value="An unexpected error occured"/>
         <property name="message" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <error xmlns="">
                  <msg>$1</msg>
               </error>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <respond/>
      </faultSequence> 
   </resource>
</api>
```

my mediate method content:

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext synCtx) {
        org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MessageContext = ((Axis2MessageContext) synCtx)
                .getAxis2MessageContext();
        try {

            // Getting the json payload to string
            String jsonPayloadToString = JsonUtil.jsonPayloadToString(((Axis2MessageContext) synCtx)
                    .getAxis2MessageContext());

            System.out.println("original payload : \n" + jsonPayloadToString + "\n");
```

I'm not being able to use the return from my SOAP call in my mediator so I can work on it.

When I run the API I get the following from my mediator code:

```
    original payload: 
    {}
```

Is there a way so I can obtain the SOAP call returned envelope and use it in my mediator?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON payload is coming as empty because you are calling a SOAP backend and getting a SOAP payload. You can use `synCtx.getEnvelope()` in your mediator to get the SOAPEnvelope from the response.

Answer (score 0):

1- make sure the json payload is there. So, log the `json` properties inside your `inSequence`.

2- `I'm not being able to use the return from my SOAP call in my mediator so I can work on it.` you can see the response payload in your `outSequence` which currently is doing nothing.

3- According to your scenario which is simply calling a SOAP webservice, you do not need a class mediator. In other words, when you do not need manipulating the initial payload and then pass it to the destination service, logically implementing your own class mediator benefits you nothing.

Also, there are quite number of samples in https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611 which will help you.

Please let me know if your problem is solved.